# Kubuntu Xenial upgrade - X11 error - "all shell packages missing"

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I recently upgraded to Kubuntu 16.04 from 15.10.  After the upgrade X windows doesn't start and I get dumped to a console window.  When I log in I can execute a 'startx' but I get the KDE error "All shell packages missing".

It seems to be related to this install kde-l10n bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1571564

Is there a workaround for this bug or do I need to wait for updated packages?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I figured out a way to get the desktop back.

1. Log in as yourself (not root) on console 1 (CTRL+ALT+F1)
2. run startx.  X11 will start
3. Hit CTRL+ALT+F2.  This will bring you to another console.
4. Login in as yourself again.
5. Type "export DISPLAY=:0" and hit Enter
6. Type "plasmashell" hit Enter
7. Switch back to X11 - CTRL+ALT+F1

The KDE desktop will be running, some icons will be missing but you'll have a 90% functional desktop.

If a fix is posted for this issue I'll add the fix here.

Comment: If your screen is set to lock automatically you can unlock by switching to another console (CTRL+ALT+F3) and executing   "loginctl unlock-sessions".   You'll get prompted for your password and the X11 session will unlock.